# AES decryption padding with PKCS5 Python

Tags: python, aes, pycrypto, cbc-mode

I have been trying to implement AES CBC decryption in Python. Since the ciphered text is not a multiple of 16bytes, padding was necessary. Without padding, this error surfaced

"TypeError: Odd-length string"

But I could not find a proper reference for implementing PKCS5 in PyCrypto Python. 
Are there any commands to implement this? 
Thanks

After looking into Marcus's suggestion I did this.

My goal actually is to decrypt a hex message(128bytes) using this code. However, the output is " ?:" which is very small and the unpad command is deleting those bytes. This is the code.

```
from Crypto.Cipher import AES
BS = 16
pad = lambda s: s + (BS - len(s) % BS) * chr(BS - len(s) % BS) 
unpad = lambda s : s[0:-ord(s[-1])]

class AESCipher:
    def __init__( self, key ):
    self.key = key 

    def encrypt( self, raw ):
        raw = pad(raw)
        iv = raw[:16]
        raw=raw[16:]
        #iv = Random.new().read( AES.block_size )
        cipher = AES.new( self.key, AES.MODE_CBC, iv )
        return ( iv + cipher.encrypt( raw ) ).encode("hex")

    def decrypt( self, enc ):
        iv = enc[:16]
        enc= enc[16:]
        cipher = AES.new(self.key, AES.MODE_CBC, iv )
        return unpad(cipher.decrypt( enc))

mode = AES.MODE_CBC
key = "140b41b22a29beb4061bda66b6747e14"
ciphertext = "4ca00ff4c898d61e1edbf1800618fb2828a226d160dad07883d04e008a7897ee2e4b7465d5290d0c0e6c6822236e1daafb94ffe0c5da05d9476be028ad7c1d81";
key=key[:32]
decryptor = AESCipher(key)
decryptor.__init__(key)
plaintext = decryptor.decrypt(ciphertext)
print plaintext
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12524994/encrypt-decrypt-using-pycrypto-aes-256/12525165#12525165, the padding functions in answer may help :)

Answer (score 25):

You need to decode your hex encoded value before decryption. If you want to work with hex encoded keys, decode it as well..

Here, this should work.

```
from Crypto.Cipher import AES
from Crypto import Random

BS = 16
pad = lambda s: s + (BS - len(s) % BS) * chr(BS - len(s) % BS) 
unpad = lambda s : s[0:-ord(s[-1])]

class AESCipher:
    def __init__( self, key ):
        """
        Requires hex encoded param as a key
        """
        self.key = key.decode("hex")

    def encrypt( self, raw ):
        """
        Returns hex encoded encrypted value!
        """
        raw = pad(raw)
        iv = Random.new().read(AES.block_size);
        cipher = AES.new( self.key, AES.MODE_CBC, iv )
        return ( iv + cipher.encrypt( raw ) ).encode("hex")

    def decrypt( self, enc ):
        """
        Requires hex encoded param to decrypt
        """
        enc = enc.decode("hex")
        iv = enc[:16]
        enc= enc[16:]
        cipher = AES.new(self.key, AES.MODE_CBC, iv )
        return unpad(cipher.decrypt( enc))

if __name__== "__main__":
    key = "140b41b22a29beb4061bda66b6747e14"
    ciphertext = "4ca00ff4c898d61e1edbf1800618fb2828a226d160dad07883d04e008a7897ee2e4b7465d5290d0c0e6c6822236e1daafb94ffe0c5da05d9476be028ad7c1d81"
    key=key[:32]
    decryptor = AESCipher(key)
    plaintext = decryptor.decrypt(ciphertext)
    print "%s" % plaintext
```