# Input string length limit in pycrypto

Tags: python, pycrypto

I am trying to encrypt my data using **pycrypto**. I have written below code for that.

```
from Crypto.Cipher import AES
obj = AES.new('1234567891011123', AES.MODE_CBC, 'This is an IV456')
message = "Jeannine"
ciphertext1 = obj.encrypt(message)
print(ciphertext1)
message1 = "Jeannine"
ciphertext2 = obj.encrypt(message1)
print(ciphertext2)
obj2 = AES.new('1234567891011123', AES.MODE_CBC, 'This is an IV456')
dciphertext1 = obj2.decrypt(ciphertext1)
print(dciphertext1)
dciphertext2=obj2.decrypt(ciphertext2)
print(dciphertext2)
```

but i am getting below error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "cipher.py", line 4, in <module>
    ciphertext1 = obj.encrypt(message)
ValueError: Input strings must be a multiple of 16 in length
```

How can i keep control in my input string ? Input string can be of any length.

Comment: You can pad strings with zero-bytes.

Comment: how can i do that ? can you please share links or code it would be helpfull.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [AES decryption padding with PKCS5 Python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12562021/aes-decryption-padding-with-pkcs5-python)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using AES in CBC mode, it requires the string in length that's multiple of 16, so you might need to add some padding.

Follow the steps described in [this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14179784/python-encrypting-with-pycrypto-aes) (this doesn't look like a duplicate to me, but the answer is useful for you).

Comment: I tried `CFB` and it worked but my encrypted result is different in both cases though the input is same. why it is behaving like that ?

Comment: Because they treat the blocks in different ways. Here's a more detailed description of how the modes work: http://pythonhosted.org/pycrypto/Crypto.Cipher.blockalgo-module.html#MODE_CBC

Comment: @animal All modes are incompatible and have different properties: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_cipher_mode_of_operation (there are much more modes, but those are the common ones)

Comment: @FernandoCezar is their any way i can get same encrypted result for same input ?

Comment: @ArtjomB. is their any way i can get same encrypted result for same input ?

Comment: @animal not with different modes. They are different ways to hash the same input, so the output has to be different.

Comment: if i am using same mode as i have used in my question. Than will it be possible ?

Comment: Thanks @FernandoCezar for your help. Please upvote my question.