# pycrypto AES passphrase greater than block size

Tags: python, encryption, aes, pycrypto

I have a quick question with reference to pycrypto AES encryption. Suppose I use the accepted answer to the [Encrypt & Decrypt using PyCrypto AES 256](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12524994/encrypt-decrypt-using-pycrypto-aes-256/12525165#12525165), and I have my passphrase to AES encryptor > 16 bytes(my block size), will the data be truncated or will it still be encrypted. Please shed some light. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I’m not sure, but you should not use the password directly as input to AES.  Instead, run your password through a [key derivation function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Key_derivation_function) like [scrypt](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/scrypt/), [bcrypt](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/py-bcrypt/), or [PBKDF2](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pbkdf2) and use that as your AES key.  See [my comment regarding KDFs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12524994/#comment30285520_12525124).

Comment: this is correct.  see the code for simple-crypt - https://github.com/andrewcooke/simple-crypt (which will support python 2 soon - there's a pull request i need to merge)