# Pycrypto AES blocks

Tags: python, encryption, stream, aes, pycrypto

Tarfile offers several modes, such as `r|`, to read and write a stream of blocks. The process is entirely done in `tarfile.open()`. Does pycrypto AES offer something similar?

I am using an implementation similar to what is described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12525165/3163618). The requirement of pad and unpad functions, as well as the IV makes using a stream more complicated.