# ValueError: Invalid padding bytes when decrypting with AES256

Tags: python, encryption, cryptography, aes, python-cryptography

I am trying to rewrite [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12524994/encrypt-decrypt-using-pycrypto-aes-256) solution using `cryptography` library, but in the process of decryption I get padding error i.e. `ValueError: Invalid padding bytes.` Here is the cipher class I have so far:

```py
import os
import base64

from cryptography.hazmat.primitives import hashes
from cryptography.hazmat.primitives import padding
from cryptography.hazmat.backends import default_backend
from cryptography.hazmat.primitives.ciphers import modes
from cryptography.hazmat.primitives.ciphers import Cipher
from cryptography.hazmat.primitives.ciphers import algorithms
from cryptography.hazmat.primitives.kdf.pbkdf2 import PBKDF2HMAC

class AES256Cipher:

    def __init__(self, password, salt):
        self.password = password.encode('utf-8')
        self.salt = salt.encode('utf-8')

        self.backend = default_backend()
        self.key = self.pbkdf2()

    def encrypt(self, plaintext):
        iv = os.urandom(16)
        cipher = Cipher(
            algorithms.AES(self.key),
            modes.CBC(iv),
            backend=self.backend
        )

        encryptor = cipher.encryptor()
        padder = padding.PKCS7(256).padder()
        plaintext = plaintext.rstrip().encode('utf-8')
        padded = padder.update(plaintext) + padder.finalize()
        ciphertext = encryptor.update(padded) + encryptor.finalize()
        return base64.b64encode(ciphertext)

    def decrypt(self, ciphertext):
        ciphertext = base64.b64decode(ciphertext.rstrip())
        iv = ciphertext[:16]
        cipher = Cipher(
            algorithms.AES(self.key),
            modes.CBC(iv),
            backend=self.backend
        )

        decryptor = cipher.decryptor()
        unpadder = padding.PKCS7(256).unpadder()
        plaintext = decryptor.update(ciphertext) + decryptor.finalize()
        unpadded = unpadder.update(plaintext) + unpadder.finalize()
        return unpadded.decode('utf-8')

    def pbkdf2(self):
        kdf = PBKDF2HMAC(
            algorithm=hashes.SHA256(),
            length=32, salt=self.salt,
            iterations=100000,
            backend=self.backend
        )
        return kdf.derive(self.password)
```

The exception is raised when code reaches `unpadded = unpadder.update(plaintext) + unpadder.finalize()` in `decrypt` method. Why is the padding failing? E.g.:

```py
password = 'dummy_password'
salt = 'IU^7862390rZI)&(*hi23q2rfbnO(*^$%#'
cipher = AES256Cipher(password, salt)

ct = cipher.encrypt('secret_string')
cipher.decrypt(ct)  # <-- ValueError: Invalid padding bytes.
```

Comment: Just to point it out, the linked pycrypto question uses `AES_CFB`, not `CBC`.

Comment: @Legorooj What's the difference? Does that affects this implementation?

Comment: Kinda - CFB doesn't require padding.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your decrypt method is extracting the first 16 bytes of the cipher as the IV, but your encrypt method never put it there. The fix is to have `encrypt` put the IV in front of the ciphertext prior to base64 encoding it.

```py
return base64.b64encode(iv + ciphertext)
```

On the decrypt side, you must properly remove it:

```py
iv, ciphertext = ciphertext[:16], ciphertext[16:]
```

Comment: I though that `modes.CBC(iv)` in `Cipher` will add `iv` by default, and that I don't have to manually add it.