# Getting Exception:TypeError: new() missing 1 required positional argument: 'mode'

Tags: python, encryption, aes, pycryptodome

I want to use AES encryption to encrypt my data I have done it before but in my laptop the method is not working and giving me same error is there any way to fix it ?
Here is the code :

```
from Crypto.Cipher import AES
def paddedKey(key):
    while len(key)%8!=0:
        key +=' '
    return key
def paddingText(text):
    while len(text)%16!=0:
        text +=' '
    return text
data = paddingText(input('Enter text to encrypt - '))
key = paddedKey(input('Enter key between 16-32 charachters - '))
if(len(key)<=16 & len(key)>=32):
    print('Key must me between 16 and 32 charachters')
cipher = AES.new(key)
ciphertext = cipher.encrypt(data)
# print(ciphertext)
# print(ciphertext.decode('cp855'))
print('Encrypted text = ',ciphertext)
```

But this code is giving me error :
**Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\shati\Desktop\Python\Research\AES_Extended.py", line 18, in 
cipher = AES.new(key)
TypeError: new() missing 1 required positional argument: 'mode'**

I am using pythone version : Python **3.6.8**
Pip version: **pip 20.1.1**
PycryptoDome version : **pycryptodome 3.9.8**

Answer (score 1):

[pycrypto](https://pypi.org/project/pycrypto/) and [pycryptodome](https://pypi.org/project/pycryptodome/) collide in using the same module name (`Crypto`), but pip allows you to install both of them at the same time.

I had installed `pycrypto`, which does **not** require the argument `mode`, but some other library I installed required `pycrptodome`, and it got installed without my knowledge, and then I had the same error described in the question.

Comment: Found out our development server was using pycrypto and our production server was running pycrptodome, and I had a hard time troubleshooting the error until I found your post. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It's obvious from error, the `new` method needs two parameters.

Check this [Encrypt & Decrypt using PyCrypto AES 256](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12524994/encrypt-decrypt-using-pycrypto-aes-256)

You have to pass the **mode** parameter to the `AES.new` function.

Comment: I used this video as reference and it worked before. After installing new windows in laptop it's not working.                    https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=i0fSS6MoNV8&feature=youtu.be&fbclid=IwAR037kNRB2zmr1pSS9NsZ5wcJVXAZFQXtjpho8Myo-0eHcLEgPO15excSbs

Answer (score 0):

The old pycrypto library [had a default mode of MODE_ECB](https://www.dlitz.net/software/pycrypto/api/2.6/Crypto.Cipher.AES-module.html#new). But that library is no longer maintained.

The newer pycryptodome fork of that library is almost completely compatible, but this is one edge case where it is not 100% compatible.

You need to change old code that created a new AES object without specifying a mode:

```
Crypto.Cipher.AES.new(key).decrypt(encrypted)
```

to now explictly specify that mode that used to be the default:

```
Crypto.Cipher.AES.new(kek, Crypto.Cipher.AES.MODE_ECB).decrypt(encrypted)
```