# I want to decode aes encrypted data in Javascript in python in aws

Tags: javascript, python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I have a Javascript-AES encrypted value that I want to decode in python with cryptography library how can I do that?
I tried it with pycrypto library by adding it as layer but the import fails with some .so error. Later, I figured that pycrypto has become obsolete.
Can someone help me decrypt the following value "U2FsdGVkX1+i0YtqcKW4tsI3witHU65dqIkgYGptHT0=" in python so it can be used in lambda aws.

Comment: It looks like it's base64-encoded, so you probably need to decode it first. And then decrypt. Not sure though.

Comment: It's AES encrypted value in the following way:
`var encrypted_user = CryptoJS.AES.encrypt(username_data, secret_passphrase_user);
        var encrypted_user_str = encrypted_user.toString();`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Encrypt and decrypt using PyCrypto AES-256](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12524994/encrypt-and-decrypt-using-pycrypto-aes-256)

Comment: [https://www.pycrypto.org] says it's no longer maintained and the import fails in aws lambda.

Answer (score 0):

This looks like OpenSSL's salted encryption format. Here's some code for that:

```py
import base64,_md5,time,itertools
from Crypto.Cipher import AES
from Crypto.Util.Padding import unpad

def get_key_and_iv(password, salt):
    password = password.encode('ascii', 'ignore')  # convert to ASCII
    keyiv = _md5.md5(password + salt).digest()
    keyiv += _md5.md5(keyiv[-16:] + password + salt).digest()
    keyiv += _md5.md5(keyiv[-16:] + password + salt).digest()
    return keyiv[:32], keyiv[32:] #key and IV

def decrypt(ciphertext, password):
    raw = base64.b64decode(ciphertext)
    salt,ciphertext = raw[8:16],raw[16:]  # get the salt
    # key/iv generation
    key, iv = get_key_and_iv(password, salt)

    # decryption
    # these next 2 lines are the big time loss, take up 85% of execution time
    cipher = AES.new(key, AES.MODE_CBC, iv) # 60%
    padded_plaintext = cipher.decrypt(ciphertext) # 25%
    return unpad(padded_plaintext,16)

ciphertext="U2FsdGVkX18XEYwomB1Gu8wkkQMPjHIo7OgtLJjNEnWUTLZBrp8MieDQjoqlKkfM"
print(decrypt(ciphertext,"password"))
```

This uses [pycryptodome](https://pypi.org/project/pycryptodome/), so install that with `pip install pycryptodome`.

Comment: The above code works fine locally. But gives an import error when run in lambda even after adding a layer with pycrypto jars. I need to make it work in lambda aws.